# YII framework: Dropdownlist rules not working

Tags: php, yii

**View:**

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
                               $model,'atb_Sem',
                               array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2'),
                               array('prompt'=>'Select a Semester')
                              ); 
?>
```

**Model:**

```
array('atb_Sem', 'required')
```

**Controler:**

```
$model->validate();
```

But the validation is not triggering if the dropdown select value is still in Prompt. i mean "select a semester".

Comment: Looks correct. Maybe you don't trigger validation, or something else. Could you provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get any syntax error?
It should be like

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'atb_Sem',
                 array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2'),
                 array('prompt'=>'Select a Semester')); 
?>
```

mind the `$form->dropDownList`.

Comment: Thanks fr the reply.Its proper, by mistake it got deleted in the post sry.. Do u have any other suggestion..@Arpit Rawat

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable jquery

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```